# Integrate Facebook SDK

Tags: android, facebook

I want to use facebook sdk for login.

I followed the facebook guide for importing the Facebook SDK and some other tutorials in the subject but still after trying to import new module, android studio wont recognize my path.

I downloaded the facebook sdk, unzipped it, and then go:

`new -> a import -> new module->` entering the path and it does not recognize the path!

Is there anything I can do? Is there somthing wrong with the SDK or android studio versions?

I'm using 1.4 android studio and 4.8.1 facebook sdk.

Answer (score 0):

To implement Facebook Login for Android using Facebook Android API in Android Studio IDE.

Create a new Project in Android Studio (set minimum SDK version as 9 or above) then Goto build.gradle (Module: app) and add the following repository and dependency,

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}


 dependencies { 
  compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.7.0'
}
```

For more check link: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started

Thanks mor